# VirtualHostの設定がおかしくなってしまいました

Tags: apache

`httpd -S`で確認すると以下のようになっています。

```
port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/example.com.conf:1)
       alias example.net
```

しかし`/etc/httpd/conf/example.com.conf`には

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

としているので`example.net`になってしまう原因がわかりません。

当然ブラウザからみると`example.com`にアクセスしているのに`example.net`が表示されてしまいます。

対応の仕方を教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

環境

Apache

Comment: `hoge.com` に関する設定だけではなく、`huga.com` に関する設定も公開したほうが、回答を得られやすくなると考えられます。

Comment: "おかしくなった"という事象の前に"何かした"という事象があるはずです。（yumでライブラリのアップデートをした、UseCanonicalNameの設定を変えた、DNSを更新した等）
また環境：Apacheとのことですがバージョンもわからなければ答えにくいかと。使用OSもですね。

至急かどうか知りませんが、投稿する前に自分以外の誰が読んでもその問いが理解できる文面かどうか、推敲することをお勧めします。

Comment: 何をしたのか分からないのであれば...しかたがないので`/etc/httpd`配下を全ファイル対象に『example.net』でgrepして、見つかったところを片っ端から調べてみるとかですかねぇ...

Answer (score 1):

質問の内容のみから素直に解釈すると、`/etc/httpd/conf/example.com.conf`の内容が

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.net
    :
</VirtualHost>
    :
<Virtualhost *:80>    
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    :
</VirtualHost>
```

になっていれば、`httpd -S`は

```
port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/example.com.conf:1)
   alias example.net
```

と表示するでしょう。この場合、`httpd -S`の出力には別に

```
port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/example.com.conf:??)
   alias example.com
```

もあるはずです